How to reserve the test execute ID based floating license?
please share details if you know how can i reserve the testexecute ID based floating license for running test complete tests.
Known information:

when test execute application start it check the available license and then only open.
if license is not available application will not open.
In the pipeline VStest task will start the test execute appication, after running tests it will close the testexecute which will release the license

senario:

pipeline which will run 10 ATP test job, which has 10 VS tests task. currently there are 3 pipeline.
if pipeline 1 is running and completed 1 test job , meanwhile job 2 start the license will be consumed by the pipeline 2, hence due to this pipeline 1 job 2 is not having license and taking more time to complete the pipeline.

expectation:

block a license, complete pipeline 1 and then only license should available for the pipeline 2

